# Issue changing Pylint naming convention in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, naming-conventions, pylint

I am trying to change the "default" naming convention that Pylint "approves" as not lint. Currently snake-naming is what it looks for and I want to change it to camelCase.

I found  somethings about this and tried the following line that I typed into a new terminal in VS Code -

pylint --generate-rcfile > ~/.pylintrc

My understanding is that this line will generate a file in the currently directory that the terminal is pointing to that I can set the naming convention within. When I enter that in I get this message back  -

pylint: The term 'pylint' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Any suggestions, pointers, reframing, assistance is welcome and needed! Thank You

Comment: The error report means that you didn't install pylint. Please install it by `pip install pylint` or check your python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

The error report means that you didn't install pylint. Please install it by pip install pylint or check your python interpreter by shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type "Python: Select Interpreter".